# RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters with Request_URI

Tags: .htaccess, docker, docker-compose, sh

Getting this error when performing docker-compose up

```
Syntax error on line 449 of /etc/httpd/conf/aem.rewrites:
RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters
exited with code 1
```

Here is the line it's complaining about:

```
RewriteRule ^/is/image/.*$ http://__PUBLISH__:4503%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue had to do with improper formatting. I used dos2unix for this file and all files related to it.